# Encrypted Text - Where to Start

Tags: algorithm, encryption

So I have an encrypted text I need to decrypt, where do I start and is there a program that automatically recognizes an algorithm ? Here is a snippet of what I need decrypted:

```
e302446c4b62c02dc77b3c896ef385c64244a83bd6702b215882d3f1b599ff69
```

Comment: There is absolutely no way to automatically recognize the algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Encrypted text is designed to resemble random numbers.  Cryptographic algorithms are designed specifically to keep you from doing exactly what you are trying to do.